# How can I make the crosshair attack indicator have a solid color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a minecraft resource pack, and I noticed the hit-delay indicator for the 1.9 combat mechanics and the crosshair change color when looking at different colors of blocks. Any chance I can disable this feature, through a json file or the like? I would prefer if I could keep the crosshair like this but it's not a big deal.

Here's what I would like it to look like all the time (except it would be better to have it be opaque):

[image: I changed the bar to be solid and red.]

And here's what happens when I look at other blocks, like sand. You can barely see the shade of blue it is!

[image: It's barely noticeable!]

My actual texture for the loading bar is solid red, and I'd like to keep it that way no matter what block I'm looking at. It would be nice if it could be fully opaque as well, but the small bit of transparency that currently affects it is fine with me.

Comment: Have you searched in minecraft gamepedia? I don't know if exists a page just for that, but searching there could be useful!

Comment: @spund3 I have, but I might as well continue searching. Something tells me the code for cross hair transparency is in the launcher itself, but I've seen a resource pack with a solid bar...

Comment: So, if you didn't found anything, maybe depends of the code (like the cursor), do you know? Maybe the colors doesn't matter because the code renders it in a different (i think) like the cursor does. Do you understand?

Comment: @spund3 Well, I suspect it is in the code, but there's a good chance that it lies in a .json file where I could edit it.

Comment: So, try it and tell us the results ;)

Comment: @spund3 Well, I have no idea where the file would be located or if it even exists.

Comment: I don't have idea also, a solution could be to make a mod that do that for you

Comment: Okay, so one fix is to simply make the loading bar white like the crosshair. You can't change the color, but minecraft makes it easily visible across all blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the few steps to archive this :

1. Open Minecraft's data directory. If you don't know how to do this, this screenshot will help you.
   [image]
2. Go to versions/The version you use
3. Open it with WinRar (or any JAR viewer)
4. Navigate to `assets/minecraft/textures/gui`
5. Open `icons.png` with an image editor. At this point you should see this:
   [image]
6. Paint them with red brush.
7. That's all! Save it and restart MC.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. I know how to change the texture. What I wanted to know how to do is make it fully opaque, as stated in my post and my screenshots. Thanks, anyway.